# gcc -Wall but suppress -Wunknown-pragmas

Tags: gcc

`-Wall` enables a warning I do not want, specifically `-Wunknown-pragmas`. How to tell GCC to suppress these warnings after it is enabled by `-Wall`?

Comment: @acidzombie24: how is `-W` option different from `-Wall`?

Comment: @eSKay: I am not sure but the difference doesnt matter in this question

Answer (score 16, accepted):

> gcc -Wall -Wno-unknown-pragmas

should work.